# Laravel wrong bind of update method with Request param

Tags: laravel

I've a problem with routing calling a "update" (PUT) method from a form with Laravel.
Routing doesn't work if I put `Illuminate\Http\Request` param in "update" because method "show" method is called instead, even if 'method' => 'put' is present in the form.
Removing `Request` param everything works fine.

Below my code.

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('profile', 'ProfileController');
```

**ProfileController.php**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
...
}

public function show($id)
{
...
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::model($profile, array('action' => array('ProfileController@update', $profile->id), 'method' => 'put', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) !!}
```

Could you help me to understand where what's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which error do you have when try call 'update'?

Comment: Which package do you use for the use of Form? and what laravel version are you running?

Comment: @ArtemLyubin: I don't have any error. The problem is if i put `Request` param in the `update` method signature the routing framework chooses the `show` method for serve form action, even if there is the hidden  `_method` field to spoof the PUT HTTP.    
If I remove the `Request` param from `update` method signature everything works fine.

Comment: @StefanoGroenland: Form package is `Collective\Html\FormFacade::class`
and the Laravel version is 5.5.12.